# How to implement step-like function in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I am frequently using the following construct to implement the Heaviside step function

```
def f(x,xm):   
   1 * (xm > c)
```

I used the same to implement the CDF of the Pareto distribution.

```
def pareto_cum(x,xm,a):
     return (1.-(xm/x)**a) * (x > xm)
```

Unfortunately this produces an error message in python 3. I don't understand why division by zero is a problem here, since always `xm>0`. That is, `x > 0` should be guaranteed by default.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x=np.linspace(0,10,100000)
def pareto_cum(x,xm,a):
     return (1.-(xm/x)**a) * (x > xm)

plt.plot(x,pareto_cum(x,2,3))
__main__:2: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
__main__:2: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7fdf026770b8>]
```

CDF of the Pareto distribution [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution](http://pareto%20distribution)

Comment: Why would it be "guaranteed by default"? You never check to make sure it's non-zero.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand something, but shouldn't `(x > xm)` be taking care of it? I would expect that the `if` condition is evaluated first.

Comment: I don't see any `if`s in your code. I don't have numpy experience, but `x > xm` will evaluate to a boolean value, then it's cast to a number since you're multiplying it. All it will do is force everything to either evaluate to 0 (if x is less than xm), or do nothing otherwise.

Comment: You're just doing math. There are no checks here.

Comment: Deleted my answer since I was over my head. Hopefully Importance's answer can help you.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help anyway. You actually partially answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an error message, it's a warning. So you can ignore it if you like. The only effect this has it that the first point of the result is `nan`. The code runs fine otherwise.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.linspace(0,10,100000)
def pareto_cum(x,xm,a):
     return (1.-(xm/x)**a) * (x > xm)

plt.plot(x,pareto_cum(x,2,3))
plt.show()
```

produces as expected:

[image]

You can get rid of the warning by not letting 0 be part of the array, e.g.

```
x=np.linspace(0,10,100000)
x[0] = 1e-12
```

You can also check inside the function

```
def pareto_cum(x,xm,a):
     x[x==0] = 1e-12
     return (1.-(xm/x)**a) * (x > xm)
```

Comment: `x[x==0] = 1e-12` is passed by value I guess. i.e. this will not change the actual data.

Comment: Of course it will change the data. Every item in x that is equal to zero will afterwards be 1e-12. But of course we only change the local variable `x` here. The global x outside the function has nothing do do with it (they just have the same name but python wouldn't know about that anyways).

Comment: OK, pass by value it is.

Comment: Well, python does not have the concept of pass-by-value, but the behaviour as seen by the programmer is mostly the same.